# Override Media Manager to Change Url

Tags: media-library, link-manager

I need to insert text for a media item when getting a media type of PDF by changing the GetMediaUrl method. This is for an RTE field. I went to override the MediaProvider, but found it was obsolete and replaced by the MediaManager. I created a class that inherits from the BaseMediaManager. Now I am wondering how to add that class to the pipeline. I see the one for MediaProvider, but can't figure out where to add one for MediaManager.

I found this for Media Provider:

```
<mediaProvider type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Which Sitecore version is used?

Comment: Currently using 8.2 update 4.

Comment: Looks like this is the issue. So would this be a duplicate question? I will flag for delete if so.
 https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7348/updated-media-item-is-not-showing-on-the-site-due-to-caching-set-on-cloudflare-c/7350

Comment: As you found out, `mediaProvider` is not a pipeline, it is a single type setting. `MediaProvider` has also (incorrectly?) been marked as `[Obsolete]` but no alternative has been provided to use, and Sitecore itself is using it as the default provider, so you'll have to ignore the warning, maybe disable it...

Comment: @jammykam yep. Not sure after all I will need to change it or not yet. I am still looking through the methods, but I need to change the text of the link. The GetMediaUrl just returns the link. I may post another question if I can't find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need register the new Media Manager using [Sitecore Dependency Injection](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/dependency_injection) (see 'Registration in code' chapter). It can be done via Service Configurator as described in the article.

#### Creating Service Configurator

Implement `Sitecore.DependencyInjection.IServicesConfigurator` interface from Kernel assembly. Please note that you need to reference [Microsoft 
Dependency Injection 1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/1.0.0) NuGet package:

```
public class ServiceConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator
{
    public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<BaseMediaManager>(s =>
            new MyMediaManager(
                new DefaultMediaManager(
                    s.GetService<BaseFactory>(),
                    s.GetService<MediaProvider>()
                )));
    }
}
```

#### Implementing Media Manager

You may inherit the `DefaultMediaManager` class as you mentioned but in case of numerous changes required (probably by different teams) [composition might be a better choise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)):

```
public class MyMediaManager : BaseMediaManager
{
    private readonly BaseMediaManager _mediaManager;

    public MyMediaManager(BaseMediaManager mediaManager)
    {
        _mediaManager = mediaManager;
    }

    public override Media GetMedia(MediaItem item)
    {
        // add you custom logic here
        return _mediaManager.GetMedia(item);
    }
    ...
}
```

#### Registering Service Configurator

Last step, add the following registration to your configuration files:

```
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <services>
      <configurator type="<younamespace>.DependencyInjection.ServiceConfigurator, <yourassembly>"/>
    </services>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to override it. The method that I needed to add the text to is not in the media manager though I found out. I started another question for that. If I needed to change the URL though you answer works.

Comment: Also, do we need to patch in the mediaprovider with new MediaManager ?