# Sitecore Get media item from url/path

Tags: media-library

I'm having issues trying to get the media image item using url/path like `/-/media/Infosite/Images/Content/Teasers/relevant-curriculum-small.ashx?modified=20170314020859&hash=3835E0B83346B4B33EB0787E69117CF560457FFA` using the dynamiclink method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314582/how-to-retrieve-sitecore-media-items-from-media-url). I also tried stripping off the querystring part but of no use.

I'm trying to retrieve the media item height/width programmatically.

FYI - These media links comes from Rich Text Editor fields in Sitecore.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The method from the link is for Dynamic Links only. Your link is a full media link. You can try replacing `/-/media/` with `/sitecore/media library/`, remove everything starting from the `.ashx`, call `MainUtil.DecodeName` on what you received and then try `Database.GetItem` with the value. But `MediaRequestHandler` does many other operations so I cannot guarantee that it works.

Comment: I had a similar question yesterday. I found I was able to debug and go through the GetMediaUrl function to actually see how the url is constructed. This also has the options for width and height. If you are having issues still retrieving them you can try and append them your self. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9699/override-media-manager-to-change-url/9712#9712

Comment: Thanks @MarekMusielak for the suggestion and it worked. I was doing everything else except calling MainUtil.DecodeName before calling Database.GetItem and that was returning null.

Comment: @RReilley - The problem is when the content editor strip off the height and width of Media link inside Rich Text Editor. My custom mediaprovider was returning height/width for all images by default otherwise.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Comment converted into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method from the link is for Dynamic Links only.

Your media url is a full media link. You can try the code below:

```
var mediaUrl = "";
var mediaPath = mediaUrl.Replace("/-/media/", "/sitecore/media library/");
if (mediaPath.IndexOf(".ashx") > -1)
{
    mediaPath = mediaPath.Substring(0, mediaPath.LastIndexOf(".ashx"));
}
mediaPath = MainUtil.DecodeName(mediaPath);
var item = database.GetItem(mediaPath);
```

But `MediaRequestHandler` does many other operations so I cannot guarantee that it works in every situation.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that `MainUtil.DecodeName` performs a direct replacement of the URL against the `<encodeNameReplacements>` element. This can be problematic if you are mixing spaces and dashes in any portion of the item path (parents, etc.). Sitecore performs extra work beyond `DecodeName` to account for this if the `ItemNameAllowMixingReplacementCharacters`setting is `true`, which it is by default. May not matter in the OP use-case, but something to look out for.