# overridding GetMedialUrl of the mediaprovider class in 8.2 update 7

Tags: upgrade

I'm currently upgrading Sitecore to 8.2 update 7 from 8.0 and have come across an issue with some custom code that overrides the `GetMediaUrl` of the `MediaProvider` class.  It states that `MediaProvider.MediaProvider()` is obsolete. Does anyone know of a solution for this or has anyone overridden this method in 8.2 update 7?

```
public class MediaProvider : Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider
{
    public override string GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item, MediaUrlOptions options)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");

        var url = base.GetMediaUrl(item, options);
        if (url.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("/-/media"))
        {
            var revision = item.InnerItem.Statistics.Revision;

            ID revisionId;
            if (ID.TryParse(item.InnerItem.Statistics.Revision, out revisionId))
                revision = revisionId.ToShortID().ToString().ToLowerInvariant();

            var revisionUrl = new UrlString(url);
            revisionUrl.Add("sc_revision", revision);
            return HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(revisionUrl.ToString());
        }
        return HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: I too have overridden this method. I'm not sure if there is a better alternative available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override Media Manager to Change Url](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9699/override-media-manager-to-change-url)

Comment: I'm not sure that is the same question. Related, but not the same.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the code for the `MediaProvider` you will notice that only the parameterless constructor is marked as obsolete:

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider" /> class.
/// </summary>
[Obsolete]
public MediaProvider()
  : this(ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<BaseFactory>())
{
}
```

This is because, in later versions of Sitecore, the `MediaProvider` can be created using the container that will inject the `BaseFactory` object into the constructor that is not obsolete.

```
public MediaProvider(BaseFactory factory)
{
    // omitted for brevity...
}
```

So its not entire `MediaProvider` class that is obsolete and you are fine to continue to override that `GetMediaUrl` method in your code.